# I need to replace : with ":" form the string "AAAA:123346hadhdhajkkd890" result like "AAAA":"123346hadhdhajkkd890" using Replace functionality in C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I need to replace the string `"AAAA:123346hadhdhajkkd890"` with `"AAAA":"123346hadhdhajkkd890"` using the `Replace` function in C#.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried so far? In what way did that not work?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to use the code below :

```
var str = "AAAA:123346hadhdhajkkd890";
str  = str.Replace(":", "\":\"");
```

in order to put **"** in **Replace** function you have to use **\"** in the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s1 = "AAAA:123346hadhdhajkkd890";
var s2  = str.Replace(":", "\":\"");
```

This is because **\"** will actually tell the compiler **"** and if simply **"** will mean the end of the string. This is known as the escape sequence.